# Unknown transparent overlay on small windows

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my website.

When I resize the browser window or access the site from a device with a small screen, a white transparent box appears from the bottom of the page and grows bigger as I resize the window.

I have no idea where it comes from and can't find the issue in my code.

To see what I am referring to, try scrolling down to the bottom of this page: [redacted] and make the window smaller.

Comment: Can we please see your code so we can help you change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like your full screen image shrinks too small as the page resizes. And when you resize, the solid background color becomes visible, appearing as like a box.

So you might need to use an approach that stops shrinking that background image when it gets to a certain point so as not to be smaller than the window-height.